# Cloud foundry plugin throws error while pushing from Jenkins CF-AppResourcesFileModeInvalid(160003)

Tags: plugins, cloud, cloud-foundry

I am trying to push app to cloud foundry from Jenkins. And it complains of this :

```
org.cloudfoundry.client.v2.ClientV2Exception: CF-AppResourcesFileModeInvalid(160003): The resource file mode is invalid: File mode '444' with path '.git/objects/pack/pack-af4cdbe6faac9d245253dafc1ecae06dc3fa5816.pack' is invalid. Minimum file mode is '0600'
    at org.cloudfoundry.util.JobUtils.getError(JobUtils.java:81)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoThenMap$ThenMapMain.onNext(MonoThenMap.java:120)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:96)
```

I have tried:

```
1.Doing chmod 666 ( and even 777) before the build step. 
2.Adding these in my .cfignore:
  scripts
.git/
.git/objects/pack/*
plugins/**/*
/.bundle
tmp/
.pack
```

3. Wiping off workspace in jenkins and app on cf before another try.

Nothing works. 
One interesting thing is after a fresh commit to .cfignore (editing a line and pushing to git) , the first build in jenkins works. Subsequent build fails.

Any help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root issue is that the [Cloud Foundry Java Client](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client) pushes the entire content of the configured path to the server.  The Cloud Foundry CLI automatically filters out source control directories (and possibly all hidden directories) this filtering out the most common places to see `< 0600`, but that’s not actually documented anywhere so we don’t match that behavior.  I’ve chatted with the lead of the CLI and they’ll document that behavior at which point [we’ll implement what they spec](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client/issues/810).

The `.cfignore` file does’t work in the client yet either, but once that is properly spec’d by the CLI team, we’d work [that issue](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client/issues/330) as well.

Comment: Good to know its already being considered for fixing in future version. Thanks .